Replaced MOSFET in BLDC driver keeps blowing
I have a motor and controller which, after a catastrophic fault destroyed one of the phase coils and the high and low side MOSFETs for the affected phase, I've repaired by rewinding the coil and replacing the MOSFETs on the controller board. After that, the device was operable, but the low-side MOSFET burned out after about 20 minutes of operation. I replaced it again, adding better thermal paste between the MOSFET package and heat sink, but it burned out exactly the same way again.
I did not have the original JMTK70N07A MOSFETs available, so I substituted STD110N8F6. As far as I can tell, this should be a strictly better part with higher current and thermal tolerances. Is there some reason I'm missing that it's not a good replacement?
I also measured (via dumping 6A through it and looking at voltage drop, since I don't have an ohmmeter accurate for coil-scale resistances) and the rewound coil resistance is significantly lower than the originals - 0.28 Ω vs 0.38 Ω. Since it's a delta configuration motor, this only puts the coil-pair resistance 15% below the original value, so it doesn't seem like that should be enough to throw anything over a current limit (peak stall current should be something like 60 A at 39 V), but maybe it's sufficient to overrun the heat sink? Still it seems odd that the same MOSFET would blow again and again when the high side ones are seeing the same currents.
Are there other likely causes I should check?

Qg of the replacement part is 5x the original.

Sometimes the gate driver and/or resistor die together with the MOSFET.

@vir: I'll try getting some of the exact part in case that's the case.

@Jens: The gate driver seems to be working - everything runs fine until the MOSFET burns out. Is there a failure mode for the gate driver that would cause that kind of fault? Resistor seems plausible. I can check that after desoldering the bad MOSFET again. Right now a bunch of stuff reads 0Ω thanks to it being there. Which resistor do you have in mind (on which side/between which two points)?

Whoever voted to close, can you please instead comment on specifically what details or clarity you think I need to add? I'll be happy to add more information but I can't do that without knowing what you want.

Wow, WTF. I asked for feedback on what is needed to make the question acceptable and all I get is more close votes with no feedback whatsoever. >_<
